# Як правильно перекласти з англійської facing ratio?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, словосполучення

Питання стосується комп'ютерної графіки - рейтрейсинг.
Перекладаю речення:

> Ми також реалізовали інші функції, такі як фейковий Френель
>   (використовуючи facing ratio) і заломлення.

Comment: А не могли б Ви пояснити, що воно означає? Бо не всі володіють англійською термінологією комп'ютерної графіки. А знаючи, що це, легше шукати.

Comment: Хм... Здається, косинус кута між напрямком камери і нормаллю до поверхні.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Російською «facing ratio» перекладають як «[коэффициент обзора поверхности](//books.google.com/books?id=_kh6YyP4WHoC&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22)».

Це є абсолютне значення (модуль) косинуса кута між напрямком камери (тобто погляду) і нормаллю до поверхні. Тобто це значення змінюється в межах від 0 до 1, наприклад: коли ми дивимося на горизонтальну підлогу згори вниз — 1, коли ми дивимося на підлогу під кутом 45° — приблизно 0.7, коли ми дивимося на підлогу, повернувши голову набік і поклавши її на підлогу — приблизно 0.

Залишається скалькувати як «**коефіцієнт огляду поверхні**» — хоч цей термін досі ніде не використовується.

Answer (score 4):

Ця відповідь - суцільне [ОД](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%96%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C).

Тут важливо зрозуміти, що означає *facing* і потім правильно це перекласти. Тут *facing* означає щось на кшталт зустрічі, зіткнення. А *facing ratio* те, наскільки *відверта* зустріч. Якщо погляд падає під кутом 90°, то відвертість зустрічі найбільша, якщо під кутом 0° - найменша. Отже, *facing ratio* можна перекласти як **коефіцієнт/показник** і далі знов варіанти: **прямоти погляду, падіння погляду.**

Гадаю, що слово *поверхня*, *на поверхню*, *з поверхнею* додавати не потрібно.

Comment: Гм, «коефіцієнт прямоти [п]огляду» (а як пояснення: «коефіцієнт близькості напрямку погляду до абсолютно перпендикулярного поверхні») — прикольно. Значно наочніше, ніж «коефіцієнт огляду поверхні».